# Backbone possible to merge data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

In a backbone application I am writing I need to combine 2 sets of data into one,

I have the following in my initialise function for a view,

```
this.model.set('tasks', new Tasks(this.model.get('item_tasks')), {
        silent: true
});


this.model.set('subTasks', new Tasks(this.model.get('sub_item_tasks')), {  
         silent:true   
});
```

Is there away I can merge these 2 pieces of data into one, to allow me to loop through?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Tasks` is a `Collection`:

```
var tasks = this.model.get('tasks').toArray().concat(this.model.get('subTasks').toArray());
```